# Enum member null in Adwords library

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-ads-api

I'm using the Google Adwords library. To create crendentials there is builder pattern provided:

```
new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
                      .forApi(OfflineCredentials.Api.ADWORDS)
                      .fromFile("D:\...\ads.properties")
                      .build()
```

This call throws a null pointer exception in my app, specifically the argument for the `.forApi()` method is null. That object is an enum member [defined thus](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/modules/ads_lib/src/main/java/com/google/api/ads/common/lib/auth/OfflineCredentials.java):

```
 public static enum Api implements OAuthConfig {
  ADWORDS("api.adwords.", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"),
  AD_MANAGER("api.admanager.", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfp");

  private final String propKeyPrefix;
  private final String scope;

  private Api(String propKeyPrefix, String scope) {
    this.propKeyPrefix =
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(propKeyPrefix, "Null property key prefix for: %s", this);
    this.scope = Preconditions.checkNotNull(scope, "Null scope for: %s", this);
  }
```

Now, how can an enum member be null? And what do I do about it?

Is this a problem with class loading? If that helps, it is a Spring Boot application.

Comment: Just to be clear: you're saying Api.ADWORDS is null? So you get the NPE in ForApiBuilder.defaultOptionals when it tries to call oAuthConfig.getInternals() ? There error isn't that getInternals() is returning null and the next call failing? (though I'm not sure how that would happen either)

Comment: Yes. Evaluating `Api.ADWORDS` in the debugger results in null. Calling `.forApi(Api.ADWORDS)` throws NPE. The call to `.getInternals()` is indeed the first attempt to access members of `ADWORDS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The `Preconditions.checkNotNull` threw a `NoSuchMethodError`, due to conflicting versions. This prevented the enum member from being properly initialized, thus staying null and causing an NPE in turn.

TIL: When an enum member is null, there properly was an error in its constructor.